# Stepwise creation of a YAML file

Tags: python, pyyaml

I am facing the following problem: I create a big data set (several 10GB) of python objects. I want to create an output file in YAML format containing an entry for each object that contains information about the object saved as a nested dictionary. However, I never hold all data in memory at the same time.

The output data should be stored in a dictionary mapping an object name to the saved values. A simple version would look like this:

```
object_1: 
  value_1: 42
  value_2: 23

object_2:
  value_1: 17
  value_2: 13

[...]

object_a_lot:
  value_1: 47
  value_2: 11
```

To keep a low memory footprint, I would like to write the entry for each object and immediately delete it after writing. My current approach is as follows:

```
from yaml import dump

[...] # initialize huge_object_list. Here it is still small
with open("output.yaml", "w") as yaml_file:
    for my_object in huge_object_list:
        my_object.compute()  # this blows up the size of the object

        # create a single entry for the top level dict
        object_entry = dump(
            {my_object.name: my_object.get_yaml_data()}, 
            default_flow_style=False,
        )
        yaml_file.write(object_entry)

        my_object.delete_big_stuff()  # delete the memory consuming stuff in the object, keep other information which is needed later
```

Basically I am writing several dictionaries, but each only has one key and since the object names are unique this does not blow up. This works, but feels like *a bit* of a hack and I would like to ask if someone knows of a way to do this better/ proper.

Is there a way to write a big dictionary to a YAML file, one entry at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write out a YAML file in stages, you can do it the way you describe.

If your keys are not guaranteed to be unique, then I would recommend using a sequence (i.e. list a the top-level (even with one item), instead of a mapping.

This doesn't solve the problem of re-reading the file as PyYAML will try to read the file as a whole and that is not going load quickly, and keep in mind that the memory overhead of PyYAML will require for loading a file can easily be over 100x (a hundred times) the file size. My ruamel.yaml is wrt to memory somewhat better but still requires several tens of times the file size in memory.

You can of course cut up a file based on "leading" spaces, a new key (or dash for an item in case you use sequences) can be easily found in a different way. You can also look at storing each key-value pair in its own document within one file, that vastly reduces the overhead during loading if you combine the key-value pairs of the single documents yourself.

In similar situations I stored individual YAML "objects" in different files, using the filenames as keys to the "object" values. This requires some efficient filesystem (e.g. tail packing) and depends on what is available based on the OS your system is based on.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this was very helpful. I was not aware of the memory overhead problem. I will check if this will be a problem for my data.